# How to recover a file overwritten with another in Linux?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, recovery

I did this on the command line(Ubuntu 12.04)

mv some_arbit_file required_file

Is there any way I can recover required_file. I had put so much work into this. I usually backup files. But, I forgot this time. Will appreciate any help.

Thanks.

Comment: You may get a better response over on superuser.com or Ubuntu stack exchange

Comment: Thanks. I am going to ask in superuser.com

Answer (score 2):

You can't "undo" your command. Maybe you can found some recovery tools that will help you...

By the way the next time, to avoid this kind of trouble I suggest you use the [`-i`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?mv) option. It will tell you if you're going to overwritte a file.

You can create aliases in `~/.bashrc` :

```
alias mv="mv -i"
#you can also add aliases to cp and rm
alias cp="cp -i"
alias rm="rm -i"
```

Comment: Try that on a large, deeply nested directory structure containing thousands of files. It might become inconvenient.

Answer (score 2):

To prevent this kind of problem in the future you need to have a backup system. It's better if this backup system does some form of version control and doesn't require any effort on your part to maintain. You don't want to be thinking about which files need backing up, it should be "all of them, yes even the contents of /tmp, every hour at least"

Using git/svn or another file versioning system is not a bad idea, but what happens if you forget to add new files to the repo? What happens if the repo itself gets deleted? What happens when you try to shovel your entire music collection into it, or want to store special unix files like pipes and symlinks? I also find git repos insanely easy to corrupt, especially if I manually delete things or move them about.

A more robust system is to first buy a new hard disk of a suitably large size - one or two terabytes should be enough. Designate this your backup drive. Then get something like [Rsnapshot](http://Rsnapshot.org) and make it work. You will then have versioned backups that can be recovered using standard file tools from a half broken machine that is booting from CD where the network isn't up after a catastrophic failure of your boot drive (yes, I am speaking from experience here).

Between Rsnapshot and Apple's TimeMachine (which works in a very similar way) I have recovered from several SSD failures, a hard disk crash and a powercut that silently corrupted half my music collection which I didn't find until a week later.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to use `photorec` from the `testdisk` package. It works when you delete a file, but I don't know actually if overwriting it counts as a deletion.

For the future, I would suggest you to use a service like Dropbox for all your important files. It allows you to recover any version of every file.

Comment: I don't think Dropbox would be an appropriate backup tool, you'd be forced to decide which files were important enough to be backed up, or pay a lot of money for more storage space. It would be better to use something like Rsnapshot.org and then buy a backup hard disk, then have a cron job run hourly to maintain it all.

Comment: @Piku, Of course you can't store everything. But I've 13gb (for free) and I find out that 'important' files (programming project, self-compiled packages, universities and so on, needs only 3.5gb. I assume the same solution fits good for a lot of other people. Of course, I have a backup of the whole system (that is about 160gb).

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this [ext3 recovery](http://carlo17.home.xs4all.nl/howto/undelete_ext3.html) page.

Because it is hard, I try to be proactive and use git in every directory. This way, when I do a mistake I can `git checkout` to get the old file back.

Comment: Thanks. I see that my file system is ext4.